# Can't connect over https from smartphone

Tags: https

I have a site that has an SSL certificate and I can connect to it fine from my desktop with `https://example.com.`  But when I try to connect from my S7 smartphone I get a big red ! warning, the `https` is crossed out,  and then the connection is made over http.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks